# Moving props to state

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, state, react-props

There is an assumption that moving props to component's state is an anti-pattern. Is therefore an explanation why this is seen when dealing with forms in React?

Comment: can you show an example?

Comment: Passing the initial value of an `<input>` as prop, then setting the state to that doesn't seem like an anti-pattern.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://medium.com/@justintulk/react-anti-patterns-props-in-initial-state-28687846cc2e

Comment: @Chris take a look at the link provided by Rick.

Comment: @ChrisG what is the reason behind this? To me it doesn't make any sense to populate the state with props data, isn't this also costly in terms of performance?

Comment: @jeremyTob The very specific case I mentioned doesn't make sense? Why not? And how on earth is a one-time action going to be costly performance-wise?